# Triple integral bound specifications

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for the simplest... and easiest explanation on how these bounds are determined using the given values. I am having trouble grasping the concept.

$$\iiint_D y  \mathrm{d}V $$

where E is bounded by the planes  x=0, y=0, z=0 and 2x+2y+z=4.

Any information on how it is correctly setup is extremely useful and i would appreciate it! thank you.

Comment: Should you be integrating over $E$, not $D$?

Comment: @dave just copied down what the problem in the book is

Comment: I posted an answer where I assume $E$ and $D$ are the same region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $D$ is bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ and $2x+2y+z=4$. So we can first integrate with respect to $z$, as we see that $z$ goes from $0$ to $4-2x-2y$ (obtained from the plane equations). Now we want to see what region in the $xy$-plane is in $D$. So we consider when $z=0$, and we look at the intercepts: so when $x=0$ we have the point $(0,2,0)$, and when $y=0$ we have the point $(2,0,0)$ (substituting the values into the fourth plane equation). So the region in the $xy$-plane is a triangle between the coordinate axes, and the line connecting $(2,0,0)$ and $(0,2,0)$, which is $y=2-x$. So then we can integrate with respect to $y$ where $y$ goes from $0$ to $2-x$, and then $x$ goes from $0$ to $2$. So the integral becomes:
$$\iiint_Dy\,dV=\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_0^{4-2x-2y}y\,dzdydx$$

Comment: so i understood most of it... i think. You got the points from just plugging into the equation of 2x+2y+0=4 (since z = 0). but where did you get the value y=2-x and x is 0 to 2?

Comment: @user3058571 So to find the bounds on $x$ and $y$ we consider the $xy$-plane only (this is when $z=0$ as you said). So to find the region in the $xy$-plane, we first know that $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$ as given by the boundaries of $x=0$, $y=0$, and that $D$ is in the 1st octant. Now we consider when $x=0$ and $y=0$ to obtain intercepts for the boundary in the $xy$-plane, and these intercepts are $y=2$ and $x=2$, which we get by plugging the values into the fourth plane equation. Then we connect those points with a line (because the region is bounded by planes), and get bounds on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @user3058571 So you can visualize that the region $D$ projected into the $xy$-plane is bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$ and the line $y=x-2$. And we get $y=x-2$ from $2x+2y+z=4$ evaluated at $z=0$.